# Does this statement in implies the set is open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Topology of the real line, does $(i)$ implies the set A is open? If so, can you give me some intuition?

$(i)$ - Let $A$ be a set. If all $a \in A$ and all real sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = a$, then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x_n: n\geq n_0\} \subseteq A$.

**What I've tried?**

Since any convergent sequence s.t. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = a$, then for all $\varepsilon >0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$ we have:

$$x_n \in (a-\varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$$

but this does not implies $ (a-\varepsilon, a + \varepsilon) \subseteq A$. If I choose $\varepsilon = |x_{n_0}|$, then can we conclude that $(a-|x_{n_0}|, a +|x_{n_0}|) \subseteq A$, for $n\geq N$ ?

This might seems trivial for most of you, but I'm at beginning of a Topology's Course and still learning the first definitions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, (i) implies that $A$ is open. Suppose that $A$ is **not** open. Then there is some $a\in A$ such that for each $\epsilon>0$, $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\nsubseteq A$. In particular, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $x_n\in\left(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n\right)\setminus A$. Now show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $a$ but is **never** in $A$, contradicting (i).